# Combine Two Numbers that Satisfies these Five(5) Conditions with R

Tags: r, arithmetic

I want two(2) numbers $\phi_{1}, \quad \phi_{2}$ such that the following five(5) conditions will be satisfied using `R`:

1. $ \phi_{1} + \phi_{2} < 1 $
2. $ \phi_{1} - \phi_{2} < 1 $
3. $ -1 < \phi_{1} < 1 $
4. $ -1 < \phi_{2} < 1 $
5. $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ are in one(1) decimal place

Comment: $$\phi_1=\phi_2=0$$

Comment: This is called a *linear program* and the subject that addresses its solution is called *linear programming.*  The particular problem of finding *a* solution is called finding a *feasible* solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brute force, not much thinking: $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are both between -1 and 1 and they are given to one decimal place. That makes them discrete and we can simply test all possible combinations of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

```
phi1 <- seq(-.9, .9, .1)
phi2 <- seq(-.9, .9, .1)
grid <- expand.grid(phi1 = phi1, phi2 = phi2)

grid$condition1 <- grid$phi1 + grid$phi2 < 1
grid$condition2 <- grid$phi1 - grid$phi2 < 1

grid$valid <- grid$condition1 & grid$condition2
valid.combinations <- grid[which(grid$valid),]

plot(grid$phi1, grid$phi2, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1,1), col = "grey", ,
      xlab = expression(phi[1]), ylab = expression(phi[2]))
points(valid.combinations$phi1, valid.combinations$phi2, pch = 16)
```

[image]